# How to fix "psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer:"

Tags: python

I'm trying to return a inventory name base on the product id.
Ex. I assign bright red ink to 4. bright red ink is the inventory name and 4 is the product id.

```
def addinginventory_ok_clicked(self):

    inventoryinput = self.inventoryname.combobox.currentText()
    product_id_input = select_product_id(inventoryinput)
    quantityinput = self,quantity_lineedit.text()
    print(inventoryinput, product_id_input, quantityinput)
```

The error message after run is:

> psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "bright red ink"

I expected to return the value of product id based on the inventory name

Comment: `,` is used instead of `.`. Check the `quantityinput` line.